# Atom package override OSX keybind

Tags: macos, atom-editor

In Atom, I installed the [sort-lines](https://atom.io/packages/sort-lines) package, and the default hotkey to sort alphabetically is <kbd>F5</kbd>. However, when I hit <kbd>F5</kbd>, it just triggers my native OS X keyboard illumination.

Comment: To get F5 on a Mac, you have to hold `Fn` (lower left) and then press `F5`.

Comment: Wow that's it... thanks

Comment: @DanLowe Is your comment worth a copy and paste as a formal answer? I would. As small as the issue, and obvious the answer, others will be stumped by the same.

Comment: @Cam_Aust sure, I wrote an expanded answer

Comment: Comprehensive. Excellent.

Answer (score 2):

### Re-bind the key in Atom

If you prefer, you could re-bind this key to something other than a function key. Open your config folder from Atom's preferences and add a binding to keymap.cson. Something like this (pick whatever key you prefer).

```cson
'atom-text-editor:not([mini])':
    'alt-s': 'sort-lines:sort'
```

You can read more about keymaps in the [Atom Flight Manual](http://flight-manual.atom.io/behind-atom/sections/keymaps-in-depth/).

### How function keys work on Macs

Pressing the key marked <kbd>F5</kbd> on a Mac keyboard will, by default, only trigger the native function of that key (which varies depending which specific keyboard you're using). For instance, for you it is one of the keyboard backlight keys. Other function keys control volume, screen brightness, and iTunes playback.

If you don't want to re-bind the Atom key as described above, you can solve this in either of two ways.

#### Use the "Fn" key

Hold the <kbd>Fn</kbd> (typically at the lower left corner) and then press <kbd>F5</kbd>. This will trigger the actual F5 function key.

#### Make the function keys the default

If you prefer the function keys to be on permanently, you can turn them on as the default. This will invert the normal behavior; The function key will be the normal keypress, and the special behavior (volume, play, mute, etc) will require holding the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key.

As described in [Apple's support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204436):

> If you prefer the top row of keys to always behave as standard function keys without holding the Fn key:
>
> 1. Choose System Preferences from the Apple menu.
> 2. Click Keyboard.
> 3. Click the Keyboard tab if it's not already highlighted.
> 4. Select "Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys"
>
> With this option enabled, the keys on the top row act as standard function keys (F1–F12). To use a feature indicated by the icon printed on a key, hold Fn while pressing the key.

It's a little different on the newer TouchBar laptops. Here, the function keys are normally not displayed, and pop into existence on TouchBar when you press the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key.

For an external keyboard on a TouchBar laptop, just use the process shown above. For the built-in keyboard, you will have to use the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key. I see no way to force the function keys to always display on TouchBar.